# How to save a record in mongoose model on creation?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm working on a Web application on Nodejs/Express with mongoose and it is supposed to have an admin user built-in the database so i won't be forced to create it with a `curl` or something everytime i ship it so i was wondering if there was something like an `oncreate` hook to initialize the database with the record only on creation.

Answer (score 0):

The administrator account can be inserted during the initialization of the web service in such a fashion that only one document with the administrator's username will be created even if the query is executed multiple times. The document can be created using an upsert query:

```
await administratorModel.update({
  // These are the document properties for the admin model
  username: "admin"
}, {
  // This is the filter that mongoose will query if is satisfied in the db
  username: “admin”
}, { 
  // If the document didn't exist in the db, 'upsert' tells mongoose to insert it 
  upsert: true 
})
```

Mongoose docs: [Model.update()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update)